# What's wrong with this MATLAB function?

Tags: matlab

I have a function, `fitness.m`. The function is defined below:

```
function A = fitness(par)
    n = size(par,1)
    l = size(par,2)
    fitness_val = zeros(1,n);
    for i=1:n
        for j=1:l
            fitness_val(i) = fitness_val(i) + str2num(par(i,j));
        end
    end
    A = fitness_val
```

I am now executing this code:

```
%par is a char array
par =

1110001101
0110010001
1100010100
0110010111
1100111100
1100000101

fitness(par)
```

My output should be

```
A =

 6     4     4     6     6     4
```

Instead it throws a weird error something like this:

```
>> fitness(par)
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Is par a string or an array of doubles?

Comment: Please elaborate on your attempt to debug this behaviour. That said, I think your function simply does `sum(par == '1', 2)`...

Comment: @EitanT you are right it simply does that ! Thanks you saved me a lot of space but still I don't get why my function does not work.

Comment: @roni It works for me. That's why I asked in what way you tried to debug it.

Comment: Have you tried `clear fitness`? Could be that you have a variable named fitness that is hiding your function

Comment: It also works for me in Octave. If you type `which -all fitness`, does it show some MATLAB built-in function(s) as well as your function?

Comment: I just ran this code and got the expected answer.  I initialized par by running: `par = ['1110001101';'0110010001';'1100010100';'0110010111';'1100111100';'1100000101']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do something like what follows and then you will not have to worry about index exceed matrix dimensions.

**par is a cell**

```
for i = 1:numel(par) 
    fitness_val(i) = sum(par{i}=='1');
end
```

This does make the assumption that par is a cell that contains the strings, but that should not be a far stretch

or in `function` format

```
function fitVal = fitness(par);
    fitVal = zeros(1,numel(par));
    for i = 1:numel(par)
        fitVal(i) = sum(par{i}=='1');
    end
end
```

**par is a matrix**

```
function fitVal = fitness(par)
    fitVal = sum(par == '1',2).';
end
```